# How to align elements of an array into columns using string.format

Tags: java, string-formatting, string.format

I'm trying to recreate **straight** columns that look similar to this using string.format:

```
14  Nigel       Nachtricht  Software Engineer           93  30
9   Inga        Issacs      Telemarketing Rep           54  32
20  Tenille     Tucker      Account Renewals Rep        74  32
35  Franklin    Fraser      Corporate Controller        91  32
39  Jonathan    Jacobs      VP Finance                  59  32
8   Henry       Henderson   Field Marketing Manager     81  33
13  Marjory     MacDonald   Software Engineer           94  33
```

This is my code I have so far, but I'm a bit stuck because it only gets the first elements right, and the pair of integers at the end don't line up. It's inefficient and a bit random - the string.format is still pretty new to me.

```
for(int i = 1; i < strLastName.length; i++)
        {
            
            String strIdFormat = String.format("%1$-5s", intId[i]);
            String strLastNameFormat = String.format("%1$-5s", strLastName[i]);
            String strFirstNameFormat = String.format("%1$-15s", strFirstName[i]);
            String strRoleFormat = String.format("%1$-15s", strRole[i]);
            String strAgeFormat = String.format("%1$20d", intAge[i]);
            String strGradeFormat = String.format("%1$10d", intGrade[i]);
            
            String[] nEw = {strIdFormat, strFirstNameFormat, strLastNameFormat, strRoleFormat, strAgeFormat, strGradeFormat};
            
            for(int j = 0; j < nEw.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(nEw[j]);
                
                if(nEw[j] == nEw[5])
                {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }
            
        }
```

This is what my code prints:

```
28   Anna           AbernathyVP Sales - EMEA                  58        74

27   Avery          AndersonJr. Account Rep                  60        73

1    Abigail        ArmstrongCEO & Chairman                   56        71

29   Brett          BurkeDirector Sales - France                  52        89

2    Benjamin       BurtonExecutive Assistant                  61        65

3    Charles        ChapmanPresident & COO                  40        71
```

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You've given 5 slots of space to the last name. They are all longer than that, and String.format resolves the impossibility of asking it to shove a 20-length string in a "%5s" slot by just overrunning. Either write code that strips off the excess if that's how you want to deal with it (`x.substring(0, 5)`), or make that `5` in your last name format a LOT larger.

Also, your 'if' to add a newline should just be `if (i == 5)`, think about it.

It's also a bit bizarre that you separately format all this out. You can just use one string format, and you don't need the `1$`. Perhaps read the docs and play around with what `String.format` can do.